# Distribution of the ratio of the sample mean of i.i.d. normally distributed variables and the sample mean of its squares

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

I wonder if there is any known probability distribution modelling the ratio of the sample mean of i.i.d normally distributed variables and a sample mean of its squares (or its variance)?

To make it more clear, I wonder how the following ratio

$r = \frac{<x>}{<x^2>}$

is distributed under assumption that $x$ is normally distributed (here <> stands for sample mean).

Something like Student's distribution, but having variance instead of standard deviation in the denominator.